# Optimizing epochs in Keras model with GridSearchCV

Tags: python, optimization, keras, neural-network, gridsearchcv

I've seen various posts / guides as well as a Udemy course suggesting that optimizing the number of epochs used to train a Keras model through [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) is a good idea.

1. When you train a model for 400 epochs you've also trained it for 200.
2. When you train a model for 400 epochs the best epoch can be any of the 400.

That said if you train a model using GridSearchCV, the approach doesn't take that into account, it only considers the last epoch when comparing different models. And when you do GridSearchCV for 200 and 400 epochs it trains a model for 200 epochs and then, from scratch, for 400 epochs.

Hence, as I see it, using GridSearchCV to optimize the number of epochs you're:

1. Training "repeated", "useless" epochs.
2. Not actually finding the best number of epochs, though the information is available.

My question is:

- Doesn't an approach that is aware of the epochs being run make more sense? Is there any reason why anyone would use the described approach in practice?
- If the described approach is a bad approach and I want to do this kind of search in a more optimized way, is there any "standard" way of doing it? Maybe Early Stopping? What if we are optimizing multiple hyperparameters? Early Stopping + GridSearchCV?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out EarlyStopping Keras callback. 
Early stopping callback stops training when a parametrized metric doesn't improve over epochs, and always returns the model which maximizes the selected metric. Also acording to your use case patience kwarg should be useful.

Check the docs here:  https://keras.io/callbacks/

To find best hyperparameters check the Keras tuner: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner

Answer (score 0):

You can even use a combination of [Keras Tuner](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner) and of an early stopping callback, this way you can optimize several hyperparameters at the same time.

When defining the tuner search function, you can add the callback :

```
import tensorflow as tf

tuner.search(
  train_data,
  validation_data=validation_data,
  epochs=number_of_epochs,
  callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=1)]
)
```

With Keras Tuner, you have different options to choose the tuner.

The library documentation has examples, or you can also see this [tutorial on how to use Keras Tuner for hyperparameter tuning](https://www.sicara.ai/blog/hyperparameter-tuning-keras-tuner).